# Decrease CPU load while calculating for a long time on AIR mobile application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am facing the follow problem :
 - There is a calculation which is calculated complex maths during the loading of the application, and it is toking considerable long time ( about 20 seconds ) on which time the CPU is used nearly on 100% and the application look like it is frozen.
Since it is a mobile application, this must be prevented, even with the costs of extending the initial loading time, but there is not direct access to the calculating code since it is inside 3rd party library.

- Is there a way to prevent AIR application most of CPU generally ?

Comment: csomakk gave an answer that can work if you need the UI immediately, but if you are dependent on the calculations finishing before the user can intelligently use the app, have you considered just a "loading" state that maybe displays an image or message on screen that says "Hang on were calculating everything to get you started.. this may take up to 20 seconds depending on your device".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On desktop, you would use the Workers API. Its pretty new, I'd recommend it for AS3 only projects. If you use flex, its better to wait a few months.
Workers is a multi-threading API, what allows you to make a UI and a Working thread. This will still use 100% of CPU, but UI won't stuck.. Here are some links to get you started:
[Thibault Imbert - sneak peek](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423), 
[Intro to as 3 workers](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world), 
[AS3 Workers livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

However, on Mobile, you can't use workers, so you'd have to break your function apart, and insert some delays there, like callLater, or setTimeout. Its hard to compose a function like that, but if it has a loop, you can insert a callLater method after every x iteration. you can parametrize both x, and the delay of callLater function to achieve perfect solution. After callLater is called, the UI will be rendered, events will be generated and catched. If you don't need them, remove their listeners, or stop their propagation with a higher priority handler. If you need, I can post some source example of callLater in a loop.

Comment: It is interesting option, but i am looking for more general solution, with actually decreasing the cpu load if possible. :|

Comment: what they could possible do with cpu load on pure math calculations ?

Comment: the ui calculations will be processed on the gpu, so it may be more responsive.

Comment: but i dont have control over the calculations since they is blacboxed inside 3rd party provider library.